# How to create a Test Suite in Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) 2013?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, mtm

Is there any way to define Test Scenarios/Suites in the MTM and relate Test Cases to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume these things from your question -

> 1. You want to create a "Scenario" and then add "Test Cases" Under that scenario.  OR
> 2. You are talking about a "Test Case" to which you want to associate a "Test Method" / "Ordered Test" OR
> 3. You're asking about the convention

*Create a "Scenario" and then add "Test Cases"*

> Scenario can be a new "Suite"(MTM > Contents > New > Suite) and you can
>   add an test case by clicking on the suite and clicking on "new" to
>   create a new "test case". This would add the test case under the test
>   suite.

*Associate a "Test Case" to a "Test Method" / an "Ordered Test"*

> Go to Visual Studio, Team > Go To Work Item > type the id of your test
>   case created in MTM > GO to Associate Automation tab(the last tab) and
>   select the Test Method/Ordered Test you want to associate with the
>   Test Case > Save and Close

*Convention:*

You can try this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286659.aspx

Let me know if you're intending something else